# Declaring variable dynamically in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, for-loop, declare

Is there way I can declare 70 different variables in a loop instead of declaring each one?

I wanted to do something like below:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 70
     Dim Para + i  AS OracleParameter
Next
```

Instead of declaring as below:

```
Dim Param1 AS OracleParameter
Dim Param2 AS OracleParameter
Dim Param3 AS OracleParameter
…
Dim Param70 AS OracleParameter
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an array:

```
Dim Param(69) As OracleParameter
For i As Integer = 0 To Param.Length - 1
    Param(i) = New OracleParameter(..)
    '' etc..
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such a method, but in looking at it, why wouldn't you use a list or a KeyValuePair using the index as the key? I would really recommend using something of that nature, even if you keep the word "Param" as part of the key.

```
Dim Parameters as New KeyValuePair(Of String, OracleParameter)

For i AS Integer = 0 To 70
     Parameters.Add("Param" & i.ToString(), New OracleParameter)
Next
```

This could then be accessed at any time using (e.g.)

```
Parameters("Param66").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is done by using an array:

```
Dim Para(70) As OracleParameter
```

To access an element of the array use Para(0), Para(1) and so on.

If you actually need seperate variables you could write a small programm that prints out the needed code lines and copy&paste these to your code file - but I don't see any reason for doing so :-)

Bye, Jens