# How to efficiently declare objects

Tags: c#, winforms, list, for-loop, declaration

I am making a game that currently has a lot of code that looks similar to this.. only for each one it has to be done 42 times. (for 42 labels on a game). is there any way to make this more efficient?

```
    List<Pointer> b1 = points.FindAll(Find1);
    List<Pointer> b2 = points.FindAll(Find2);
    List<Pointer> b3 = points.FindAll(Find3);
    List<Pointer> b4 = points.FindAll(Find4);
    List<Pointer> b5 = points.FindAll(Find5);
```

each one must be a list. points is a seperate list, Find1 etc are bool methods. each of these also having 42 declarations. each Find method is like this.

```
   private static bool Find1(Pointer n)
    {
        if (n.colour.Name == "ff006000")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i know its not possible to use a for loop and have each one named like:

```
   for(int i = 1; i < 43; i++)
   List<Pointer> ("b" + i)...
```

would i need a list of methods to be able to implement something like:

```
   List<Pointer> ("b" + i) = points.FindAll(Find[i]);
```

Furthermore i then need to declare 42 objects of Areas:

```
   Area tempArea1 = new Area(b1, "Alaska");
   //after all 42 it then adds all 42 objects to an areas list
   areas.Add(tempArea1);
```

is there a more efficient way?
also this question is different as the questions asked on this i have seen do not require multiple lists to be used in multip methods, to be used in multiple declarations of objects as well as adding each object to a list. requiring a more sophisticated method than those given in answers elsewhere.

Comment: If you can't use arrays/dictionaries and must use individual variable I still believe question I pick as duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646020/variables-in-a-loop) serves as reasonable answer "no"... Clarifying why you have such strange requirement to use variables may help to find better duplicate (generating arrays of delegates via reflection or some template engine may be better fit) or qualify for re-open.

Comment: I saw your edit at the end of your question. You should post that kind of edit as a comment to make it clear that you're asking for clarification - an edit to your question can be easily overlooked.

Comment: Now, as far as I can see, what you are asking and duplicate question looks one and the same. Can you please clarify why it is you think that they are different? I don't understand what you mean by "do not require multiple lists to be used in multip methods", "multiple declarations of objects", and "adding each object to a list". And once you explain them, how does this require a more sophisticated solution? What do you think you need?